# Bootstrap grid alignment

Tags: html

Can some one check my code and tell me why `<br>` tags aren't working after `<textarea>` tags `<br>` and why things messed up after the Date field?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#dateRangePicker').datepicker({
                    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                }).on('changeDate', function(e){
                    $('#dateRangeForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Some text here</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>Full Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" style="width:400px;"/>
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>Father's Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" style="width:400px;"/>
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>Permanent Residential Address:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" style="width:400px;"></textarea>
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>Address for Communication:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" style="width:400px;"></textarea>
        </div><br><br>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>Date:</label>
        </div>   

        <div class="col-sm-3 input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" style="width:400px;"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div><br><br>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>Age as on Date:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" style="width:400px;"/>
        </div><br><br>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>Caste:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <label>SC</label>
            <input type="radio"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <label>ST</label>
            <input type="radio"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <label>OBC</label>
            <input type="radio"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <label>GENERAL</label>
            <input type="radio"/>
        </div><br><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add spacing below an element (in this case ) you should really use CSS. It gives you a lot more control, and you can be more certain that different browsers have the same result.

Seeing as you're already using inline styles in this document, you could do it by saying

```
        <div class="col-sm-9" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
```

Generally inline styles is not a good idea - you should really have it in a seperate file, using classes and ID's but i assume you know that :)

Comment: thanks! margin-bottom did the trick for spacing between my two textareas, anything on the Data field, it's not getting aligned properly?

Comment: Well, you can always "fix" it with CSS as i just told you. I dont know why bootstrap isnt aligning as it should.

Comment: You can "fix" it like this: (Please note, this is an awful hack and this should be an exception, not a rule as something you do:)

`<div class="col-sm-3 input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker" style="padding-left:13px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" style="width: 365px;">
            <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the code and it seems as though you don't understand what the

```css
<br>
```

tag is used for, but as explained here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp  it inserts a single line break.  Hope that helped!

Comment: forgive the way I've stated my question, please try running the code and check the output, you'll understand my problem that way better. :)

Comment: I see! There isn't space between the text fields.  Did you try putting in a margin using CSS instead of trying to do it all in HTML? That might work better and be more consistent!

Comment: yes! "margin-bottom" did the trick for vertical spacing between textarea tags,  Date column is being troublesome, unable to find exactly why it isn't getting aligned.

Answer (score 0):

There are few modifications needed in your code.

**Problem**

1. `<br>` tag inserts line break which adds extra space between elements.
2. The `Date` field is getting misaligned because of incorrect use of `input-group` class.
3. There is no semicolon (;) after `&nbsp`. Correct syntax is `&nbsp;`

**Solution**

1. You can eliminate the need of `<br>` tags by wrapping each element inside `form-group`
2. To align Date, create a child container with class `input-group`.
3. `&nbsp;` is not needed. This is not the standard way of writing HTML. Use `margin` instead.

Have modified your code with above fixes. Check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxb06sj6/)

Comment: hey! thanks, everything looks the right way till the Date label and it's Textbox, I tried to implement the for-group like you did above but, it's all getting unaligned after the Date label and it's textbox, sorry for the trouble :"(

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

            <!-- jQuery library -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
            <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                $('#dateRangePicker')
                    .datepicker(
                    {
                        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    })
                    .on('changeDate', function(e) 
                    {

                        $('#dateRangeForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
                    });
            });

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Some text here</h1>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>Full Name:</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" style="width:400px; margin-bottom: 10px;" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">  
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>Father's Name:</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" style="width:400px; margin-bottom: 10px;" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>Permanent Residential Address:</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" style="width:400px; margin-bottom: 10px;"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>Address for Communication:</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" style="width:400px; margin-bottom: 10px;"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>Date:</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" style="width:400px; margin-bottom: 10px;" />
              <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
                 Things messed up from here ------>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <label>Age as on Date:</label>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" style="width:400px; margin-bottom: 10px;"/>
                </div>
        </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <label>Caste:</label>
                </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <label>SC</label>
            <input type="radio"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

            <label>ST</label>
            <input type="radio"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

            <label>OBC</label>
            <input type="radio"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

            <label>GENERAL</label>
            <input type="radio"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label>Educational Qualification:</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" style="width:400px; margin-bottom: 10px;"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>Sports Event / Game:</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select class="form-control" id="usr" style="width:400px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <option>Inspector of Income Tax</option>
                <option>Tax Assistant</option>
                <option>Stenographer-Gr. II</option>
                <option>Multitasking Staff</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label>Details of Best Performance:</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" style="width:400px; margin-bottom: 10px;"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>

</html>
```